# Change color of different widgets altogether in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, colors

I want to change the different configuration colors of different widgets altogether to a same color when the user clicks on the entry widgets.

I've created a function "change_color(color)" where all my widgets are getting configured to the color passed as an argument.

The problem is the code has a lot of widgets and I've to manually add every widget to the function to keep them updated. I can't use a list as some widgets options are different, for eg: changing foreground of entry widget, background of labels, and much more. Please let me know if there is a better approach of doing this.

Here is a small example of my program. My main code is very long and is not suitable to post here.

```
import tkinter as tk

def change_color(color):
    "Change color of widgets."
    window.config(bg=color)
    user_label.config(bg=color)
    pass_label.config(bg=color)
    user_entry.config(highlightbackground=color)
    pass_entry.config(highlightbackground=color)
    user_entry.config(fg=color, insertbackground=color)
    pass_entry.config(fg=color, insertbackground=color)

window = tk.Tk()
# username
user_label = tk.Label(window, text='Username')
user_entry = tk.Entry(window, bg='black')
# password
pass_label = tk.Label(window, text='Password')
pass_entry = tk.Entry(window, bg='black')
user_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
user_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
pass_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
pass_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)
# changes color
user_entry.bind("<1>", lambda _: change_color("#99c9ff"))
pass_entry.bind("<1>", lambda _: change_color("#ffaf99"))
window.mainloop()
```

I hope you can get an idea from this example. If something is not clear please ask me from the comment section.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! You can try [`ColorVar`](https://github.com/Saadmairaj/tkmacosx/tree/master/tkmacosx#colorvar-variable) from [tkmacosx](https://pypi.org/project/tkmacosx/) library. It is a Tkinter variable that can change the color of any widget with different color options.

Comment: @Saad: ColorVar looks useful, can you apply to my sample code and show me how to do it? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can go through all widgets recursively using `winfo_children()`:

```
def change_color(color, container=None):
    if container is None:
        container = window  # set to root window
    container.config(bg=color)
    for child in container.winfo_children():
        if child.winfo_children():
            # child has children, go through its children
            change_color(color, child)
        elif type(child) is tk.Label:
            child.config(bg=color)
        elif type(child) is tk.Entry:
            child.config(highlightbackground=color)
            child.config(fg=color, insertbackground=color)
        # check for other widget types ...
```

Comment: Thanks acw1668!! Your function works well but i'll go with Saad's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach to doing it.

```
import tkinter as tk

def change_color(color):
    "Change color of widgets."

    for wdg in window.children():
        wdg = window.nametowidget(wdg)
        if isinstance(wdg, tk.Label):
            wdg.config(bg=color)
        elif isinstance(wdg, tk.Entry):
            wdg.config(fg=color, insertbackground=color, highlightbackground=color)


window = tk.Tk()
# username
user_label = tk.Label(window, text='Username')
user_entry = tk.Entry(window, bg='black')
# password
pass_label = tk.Label(window, text='Password')
pass_entry = tk.Entry(window, bg='black')
user_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
user_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
pass_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
pass_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)
# changes color
user_entry.bind("<1>", lambda _: change_color("#99c9ff"))
pass_entry.bind("<1>", lambda _: change_color("#ffaf99"))

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: My original code is very big and it has multiple change_color functions, this might short it by some lines but it will not change the configuration of widgets inside a frame.